# How to change the number of columns of a 2D array in python?

Tags: python

In the below snippet of the code (which is written just to show the issue), I have initially created a 2D array of size 3*4. Now during the execution of the code, at some time step, I need to change the number of columns in the third row from 4 to 2. I tried by the folowing way but it is showing the value error. How to do this ? Can somebody describe ?

```
import numpy as np
A=np.ones((3,4))

# Some other portion of the code
 
for i in range(0,3):
    if(i==2):  # In the third row
        A[i,:]=np.ones(2)  # Change the size of this third row.Now only need two elements (two 1's) in it 
print(A)

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2) into shape (4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Numpy only support the new row has the same dimension as the input of column (4 for your example).

You can change from Numpy to list.

```
import numpy as np

A=np.ones((3,4))
A = A.tolist()
for i in range(0,3):
    if(i==2):  # In the third row
        A[i] = [1]*2
print(A)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the dimension of a structured data table,
You could try:

```
A=np.ones((3,4))
row_no = 2
for i in range(0,row_no+1):
    if(i==row_no): 
    A[i,:row_no]=np.ones(2)
    A[i,row_no+1:]= np.nan #or 0 or somr other placeholder
print(A)
```